# compile libev (dev) under CentOS

Tags: libevent, event-loop, libev

I was wondering if there were instructions somewhere on how to compile [libev-dev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) on Linux (CentOS) 64 bit. I was not able to locate the dev package associated with libev nor any tutorials on its compilation.
p.s: no package managers please - since I am installing on the cloud with no previliges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, download the source package and unzip it to somewhere.
And then try this:

```
cd /path/to/libev
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

It works for me. Hope it also works for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I am wondering why the need for 'autogen.sh' since, for example, 'configure' and 'makefile.in' files already exist ?!

Answer (score 1):

If you not have privilege to root, you may make it but not install it. 
Just simply cp *.o file to your program and use something like `gcc -o test test.c ev.o`.

Answer (score 0):

Since today libev is using cmake for the compilation, then here is a bit more updated answer:

```
cmake .
make
sudo make install
```

And if you don't have privileges you can the installation directory by:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${INSTALLATION_DIR}/usr
make
make install
```